# docker host and container disk usage issues

Tags: docker

I have two docker cluster nodes, I create a container on each node and run the df -hl command, where one container rootfs is equal to the size of my host root partition, but the other container rootfs shows only 10G, two The docker version of the host is the same.

```
***1.host:***
[root@dockerun4 ~]# df -hl
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md126p3    915G   23G  893G   3% /
devtmpfs        9.8G     0  9.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           9.9G     0  9.9G   0% /dev/shm
***1.container:***
[root@717eb4539c48 /]# df -hl                                                                                                                                            
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                                                                                                                         
rootfs          915G   23G  893G   3% /                                                                                                                                  
overlay         915G   23G  893G   3% /   
***docker version***
[root@dockerun4 ~]# docker -v
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
***2.host***
[root@dockerun3 ~]# df -hl
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       440G  383G   58G  87% /
devtmpfs         48G     0   48G   0% /dev
tmpfs            48G   84K   48G   1% /dev/shm
***2.container***
[root@aea7052147cb /]# df -hl                                                                                                                                            
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                                                                                                                         
rootfs           10G  1.7G  8.4G  17% /                                                                                                                                  
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
***docker version:***
[root@dockerun3 ~]# docker -v
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

---

Someone can tell me how this is going on, because the container size of the rootfs 10G space is not enough

Comment: Are your two nodes using the same docker storage driver?

Comment: I have just checked a bit, is different, one is devicemapper, one is overlay, how to amend the devicemapper for the overlay, and to ensure that the existing container is still able to run